# How to pass div id, class as parameters to a function called by an anchor tag onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I am trying to pass table id, div id and nested class names into a generic function that's used across the programme code.

The tricky part is, this function calls another function which is wrapped within an anchor tag's onclick event. Before adding the two additional parameters, the function `removeItem` worked and now no longer fires. These two parameters are required in order to make the function reusable.

The jsfiddle of the [expected programme.](http://jsfiddle.net/ee8tb2dr/1/)

Both ids (the parameters) are passed as strings quoted,

```
var tableid = "'#tble1200'"
var otherid = "'div.class1 .total'"

function AddProduct(elment, event, tableid, otherid)
{
   //do something
   //the hyperlink is remove
   remove: '<a href="#" class="remove" 
   onclick="removeProduct(this, event,tableid,otherid)">X</a>'
}

function removeProduct(element, event, tblid, othid)
{
    //do something
    $(tblid).datagrid('loadData', data);
    $(othid).html('Total: $'+subTotal);
}
```

I am trying out the code from [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474829/remove-button-for-drag-and-drop-shopping-cart-using-jquery) jsfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/6/) : The original code.

```
function addProduct(name,price){
        function add(){
            for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
                var row = data.rows[i];
                if (row.name == name){
                    row.quantity += 1;
                    return;
                }
            }
            data.total += 1;
            data.rows.push({
                name:name,
                quantity:1,
                price:price,
                remove: '<a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeProduct(this, event)">X</a>'
            });
        }
        add();
        totalCost += price;
        $('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data);
        $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how these functions are used? Passing JS code as a string is not something you want to be doing - it works, but you can't really bind scope the way you want.

Comment: @Halcyon there's an example I have been [using here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17511571/2061309) Instead of having one cart, there are multiple carts. And I do not want to have duplicate addProduct and RemoveProduct functions. Instead I would like to reuse these two functions for all the cart's. That's why I am using a way to parameterized the underlying element ids

Comment: I don't really care about the `removeItem` function, it's the `main` function I'm interested in. How are you using this function?

Comment: @Halcyon I updated my post. If JS code isn't passed as a string, what other choices do I have here?

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle with the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Regardless of where I drop an item, it shows up under cart 1. The remove button seems to work in your fiddle...

Comment: @bernland http://jsfiddle.net/ee8tb2dr/1/ it's the same as above. Items do get dropped into both as expected. The remove buttons works for only first cart. Second one it doesn't. And prime intention here is to avoid duplicating addproduct and removeproduct functions for each cart...

Comment: Can you elaborate more on carts functionality you want, are carts independent or second cart is clone. I mean when you add / remove a product in one cart do you want product added / removed in both cart or related cart

Comment: @ManojYadav great to see you hear. All carts are independent of each other. There are few categories of items. Within one category, number of items (e.g. the lists). So each carts total, each item's quantity (in the category) is something I want to update as per transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple carts to work independently you have to store cart data in and `array` with `index`. And pass the `index` to `addProduct` and `removeProduct` `functions`. And for cart content use `class` instead of `id`

Updated code is as below:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Multiple Carts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;background:#fafafa;">
        <ul class="products">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt1.gif"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Balloon</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Feeling</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt3.gif"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Elephant</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt4.gif"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Stamps</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt5.gif"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Monogram</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item">
                    <img src="images/shirt6.gif"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Rolling</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cart">
            <h1>Shopping Cart 1</h1>
            <div style="background:#fff">
                <table class="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width:300px;height:auto;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                            <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                            <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                            <th field="remove" width=60 align="right">Remove</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <p class="total">Total: $0</p>
            <h2>Drop here to add to cart</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="cart">
            <h1>Shopping Cart 2</h1>
            <div style="background:#fff">
                <table class="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width:300px;height:auto;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                            <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                            <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                            <th field="remove" width=60 align="right">Remove</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <p class="total">Total: $0</p>
            <h2>Drop here to add to cart</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.products{
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:300px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
}
.products li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.item{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.item img{
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.item p{
    margin:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#c3c3c3;
}
.cart{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    width:300px;
    height:50%;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
.cart:nth-child(odd){
    top:50% !important;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
    color:#555;
}
h2{
    position:absolute;
    font-size:16px;
    left:10px;
    bottom:20px;
    color:#555;
}
.total{
    margin:0;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var data = [];

$(function () {
    $('.cartcontent').datagrid({
        singleSelect: true
    });
    $('.item').draggable({
        revert: true,
        proxy: 'clone',
        onStartDrag: function () {
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
            $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index', 10);
        },
        onStopDrag: function () {
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'move';
        }
    });
    $('.cart').droppable({
        onDragEnter: function (e, source) {
            $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'auto';
        },
        onDragLeave: function (e, source) {
            $(source).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
        },
        onDrop: function (e, source) {
            var $source = $(source);
            var name = $source.find('p:eq(0)').text();
            var price = $source.find('p:eq(1)').text();
            addProduct($('.cart').index($(e.currentTarget)), name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
        }
    });
});

function loadData(cartIndex, event) {
    var $cart = $('.cart:eq(' + cartIndex + ')');
    $cart.find('.cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data[cartIndex]);
    $cart.find('.total').text('Total: $' + data[cartIndex].total);
}

function addProduct(cartIndex, name, price) {
    function add() {
        if (!data[cartIndex]) {
            data[cartIndex] = {
                length: 0,
                total: 0,
                rows: []
            };
        }
        for (var i=0; i < data[cartIndex].length; i++) {
            var row = data[cartIndex].rows[i];
            if (row.name === name) {
                row.quantity += 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        data[cartIndex].length++;
        data[cartIndex].rows.push({
            name: name,
            quantity: 1,
            price: price,
            remove: '<a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeProduct(' + cartIndex + ', this)">X</a>'
        });
    }
    add();
    data[cartIndex].total += price;
    loadData(cartIndex);
}

function removeProduct(cartIndex, el) {
    var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
    var name = tr.find('td[field=name]').text();
    var price = tr.find('td[field=price]').text();
    var quantity = tr.find('td[field=quantity]').text();
    for(var i = 0; i < data[cartIndex].length; i++){
        var row = data[cartIndex].rows[i];
        if (row.name == name) {
            data[cartIndex].rows.splice(i, 1);
            data[cartIndex].length--;
            break;
        }
    }
    data[cartIndex].total -=  price * quantity;
    loadData(cartIndex);
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1rqbap/1)**

Comment: `And for cart content use class instead of id` : how does it make a difference in the functionality? Your approach doesn't get affected by jquery scoping issue, because you use an array to store rather than just a unique index like the below answer? Can you please explain? This is already a fantastic solution.

Comment: Because you can't use same `id` for multiple `elements` on same `document` but you can use same `class` for multiple `elements`. Otherwise `$cart.find('.cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data[cartIndex]);` will not work and you have to handle multiple `id` and load relevant `datagrid`

Comment: @Manjoj I managed to [get it solved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30511548/2061309) and learnt fairly great stuff on the way. Thanks much for giving me the first direction and this code. Although it's just a learning code to me, it helps heaps. I got slapped by downvotes all the way and some even came here to downvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

`functoin AddProduct(elment, event, tableid, otherid)`

**functoin** is spelled incorrectly, it should be **function**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will work:

```
remove: '<a href="#" id="item-' + unique_nr + '" class="remove">X</a>'

// later

$("#item-" + unique_nr).click(function (event) {
    removeProduct(this, event, table_id, cart_id);
});
```

Using the `id` you can fetch the item later and bind a scope listener.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/135/

Right now I'm passing `table_id` and `cart_id`, you could consider passing the actual table and cart, ie. `$("#cartcontent")` and `$(".cart")`

Keep in mind that `".cart"` is not unique, so if you want to have two lists you will need to make it unique.

Comment: Could you please explain this `Using the id you can fetch the item later and bind a scope listener.` with regards to the `$("#item-" + unique_nr).click`? It is well beyond my current understanding. How does the `unique_nr` works?

Comment: Also there's a [slight problem with the `data` array.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/136/) It gets updated by both carts. So I may have to pass that as a parameter too. I would like to know if I have to have 2 duplicate functions for two carts? Any way to reuse the same function which implements drag, drop?

Comment: That's just great. I am not sure if you had tried out adding few items to both carts at once. The remove doesn't seem to work and stuck at one item...what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I think the datagrid always re-renders the nodes so the event listener disappeared. This works : http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/140/ What you see happening here is that you're bumping against the limitations of jQuery. You get all these strange bugs because jQuery has no way to do scoping properly.

Comment: It is not a must for me to use jQuery if this entire thing can be done in javaScript, really. Infact this current programme is using external UIs, which is not in my best interest. Can you advice if this drag and drop can be achieved similar way in javaScript? My backend for database is handled in Asp.Net (classic, not MVC). If that's a yes, then that's the take away I learn from you :)

Comment: Rather than having unique_nr as a digit, if it is used as an array, perhaps the scope issue can be solved? Because I see that it's still having such issues.

Comment: The `unique_nr` services the purpose of being able to find the element `datagrid` just added for us. This problem arises because there doesn't seem to be a nice way to pass nodes to datagrid. If you try to pass a DOMNode it will render as `[object Object]`. Here is a theoretical example that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/141/ if you ditch jQuery (and datagrid in particular) you can make it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78454/discussion-between-aspiring-and-halcyon).