# What does -1 index of an element mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to debug the jquery/js code below. So I was looking for the index of the elements. However it's returning `-1`.

In [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1rqbap/1/) it is working well. But when migrating to asp.net IDE, this is giving `-1`.

The markup:

```
<div class="cart">
   <h2>Cart 1</h2>
   <p>Books </p> 
     <table class="cartcontent" data-options="fitColumns:true, singleSelect: true">                                
         <thead>
           <tr>
               <th data-options="field:'name',width:100">Name</th>
               <th data-options="field:'quantity',width:100">Quantity</th>
               <th data-options="field:'balance',width:100,align:'right'">Balance</th>
               <th data-options="field:'remove',width:100,align:'right'">Remove</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
</div>
```

jquery/js:

```
function loadData(cartIndex, event) {        
    alert($('.cart').index());
    var $cart = $('.cart:eq(' + cartIndex + ')');   
    alert($cart.index()); //returns -1
    $cart.find('.cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data[cartIndex]);    

}
```

why is it returning `-1` index here and what does this `-1` mean?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/index/  `If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.` Are you sure the `.cart` elements exist in the DOM when `loadData()` is called?

Comment: Means it wasn't found. Are you sure `$('.cart:eq(' + cartIndex + ')')` exists?

Comment: @JoshStevenson It shows a lack of research effort. Like going to the docs for the method in question. That's what the downvote button says after all

Comment: @RGraham it's been a struggle. There's only one table in this entire markup. So I am testing `cartIndex` for zero. Here's the [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1rqbap/1/). The issue is, it works in jsfiddle, but when I am now migrating it into asp.net IDE it just doesn't work.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the *actual* problem might be if you can't even reproduce it.

Comment: what is the value of `alert($('.cart').length);` also what is the value of `alert(cartIndex)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny `alert($('.cart').length);` returns 0. And `cartIndex = 0`

Comment: @aspiring that is the problem there are no elements with class `cart` in your page

Comment: @aspiring but when the script is executed such an element does not exist.... whether the elements are loaded dynamically

Comment: `$(.cartcontent).index()` is returning 2 because it is the 3rd child of the `.cart` element. first being `h2` and second `p`... what is the expected value

Comment: @aspiring are there multiple cart elements... is there any ajax requests involved in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-1` means the object cannot be found in the array.

`$cart.index()` returns `-1`, hence whatever is in `$cart` can not be found. One line above, you assign `$('.cart:eq(' + cartIndex + ')')` to `$cart`. Hence the selector `.cart:eq(' + cartIndex + ')'` matches no element in your html.

Answer (score 2):

It means the jQuery object `$cart` does not contain any element

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Granted, it's a bit terse and could have an explanation of what's happening but it's not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping out with all the ideas that I couldn't have thought of.

One of the main reasons the code didn't work as expected was due to the fact that jquery/js script function was called before DOM was loaded. That's what @Rory McCrossan first commented. I went through searching and landed on [this article: Running Your Code at the Right Time](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/running_your_code_at_the_right_time.htm).

@AmmarCSE from my earliest post actually asked me *"so you mean you have a click handler attached to .cart and inside you want to load the table?"*

I had no idea what that was in the context of jquery/javascript and this whole web thing. However that helped me a lot to understand perhaps I need an `eventlistener` and to think further why I must use a button click event and how pageload/domload doesn't suit this scenario.

@Arun P Johny stated many ways to find out if the elements are existing while running the code.

I put the js code execution here:

```
</body>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDomHasLoaded, false);
        alert("haha DOM content is loaded");
        function theDomHasLoaded(e) {
            addAll(0, e);
        }
    </script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cart_Test.js"> </script>

</html>
```

Coming from C# background with fairly comfortable VS IDE with great debugging facilities, I realized debugging jQuery, js codes are rather tedious.

Since this was a test to place the migration skeleton from jsfiddle to asp.net, I tried out with pageload, domload events. However in actual implementation I want to load these cart html tables on a button click event. By then entire DOM is anyway loaded. I learnt alot here today, thanks guys.